# The make () function in js node, what is it used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, adonis.js

I found the const users = make('App / Services / UserService') function in my friend's project, is the make() function exactly the use() function?

Answer (score 1):

`use()` comes with `express`. For e.g,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client")));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

`make` seems to be a custom function somebody defined in your project. If you debug the function, you'll get to know what it does.